# Actually pulling with git

Tags: git

I have a git repo in GitHub. I've been mostly using `git gui` to manage it up to now, but now I'm starting to use the shell. What I want to know is, how do I fetch all the branches in a remote and merge them into the respective branches on my local repo automatically? For example, if I have branches `master` and `development`, and thus `origin/master` and `origin/development`, I want to fetch `origin/master` and merge it into `master` and to fetch `origin/development` and merge it into `development`.

Is there a command that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list the local branches:

```
$ git branch
*  master
```

To list available remote branches:

```
$ git branch -r
* master
  branch1
  branch2
```

Now it gets interesting, To track a remote branch1:

```
$ git branch --track branch1
```

This enables a pull to also update the branch locally.

Simply switch to the new branch with:

```
$ git checkout branch1
```

By using the --track parameter, the remote branches are added to .git/config and will become persistent. ie this only needs to be done once. The pertinent entries from .git/config will show like this:

```
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.branch1.remote=origin
branch.branch1.merge=refs/heads/branch1
```

By running branch --track commands for each of the remote branches you would like to have locally will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a single command that will fetch and merge all branches simultaneously. The [`git pull`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) command:

> Runs *git-fetch* with the given parameters, and calls *git-merge* to merge the retrieved head(s) into the current branch.

So it only works on the current branch.  This is necessary because you need to be in a position to deal with conflicts when they arise.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the branch names in question, you can set this up so it happens on a

```
git pull
```

by editing the .git/config file.

See

```
man git-pull
```

for more details: (cloned from man git-pull below)

```
   o   Command line pull of multiple branches from one repository:

           $ git checkout master
           $ git fetch origin +pu:pu maint:tmp
           $ git pull . tmp

       This updates (or creates, as necessary) branches pu and tmp in the
       local repository by fetching from the branches (respectively) pu
       and maint from the remote repository.

       The pu branch will be updated even if it is does not fast-forward;
       the others will not be.
```

Comment: You can do that for a `git push`, but can you do the same for a `git pull`?

Comment: Sort of.  You can tell it to fetch and update all remote tracking branches, and pull the current branch.  The other branches you have will need to be manually merged.  Note that a pull on a branch branched from a remote tracking branch will merge from the remote tracking branch.

Comment: And the man page claims you can do the real deal, too.  I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in a file named pull-all:

```
#!/bin/bash
git fetch origin
git checkout development
git merge origin/development
git checkout master
git merge origin/master
```

Then, give pull-all executable permissions and put it into a directory on your path.  Usually, $HOME/bin:

```
chmod +x pull-all
mv pull-all $HOME/bin
```

Comment: This may need manual intervention if there are any conflicts in the merge that cannot be automatically resolved.

Comment: Problem with this is I will have to modify this every time I add new branches.