# git: branches diverged; how to proceed?

Tags: git, git-rebase

My local tree has diverged from the master:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 7 and 3 different commit(s) each, respectively.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I tried **git pull --rebase** and failed:

```
$ git pull --rebase
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: * ...
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging ChangeLog
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in ChangeLog
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 * ...
```

So I reverted with **git rebase --abort** and I am now at square 1.

What I want is:

1. "Export" my 7 patches into human readable diff files (a la **hg export**).
2. Make my tree a carbon copy of the origin/master (a la **hg strip**).
3. re-apply my 7 patches one-by-one by hand (a la **hg import**).

I do understand that **git rebase --continue** does this.
I did it and it did work (after a few manual merges and a **git add**).
However, I want to be able to do that manually, 
so I am wondering what are the **git** commands corresponding to the **hg** commands above.

Thanks.

PS. Please do not tell me that using a **ChangeLog** file with **git** is stupid.
Even if it is, it is not up to me.

Comment: 1. git merge origin/master. 2. git pull --no-rebase. Since your commits are huge, pulling without rebase will be easier.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There are, of course, several ways you could do this manually. You'll still have the same conflicts because git is basically doing this for you under the hood. But if you want to do this manually, here are a couple of ways.

First, export your commits as a series of patches. The easiest way to do this is using `git format-patch`:

```
git format-patch -M @{upstream}
```

will produce 7 patch files -- one for each of your commits. (Note that "@{upstream}" is literal -- it's a not so well known feature of git.) This is better than capturing the output of `git diff` because all of the commit information (author, date, message, etc.) are preserved.

Then you could reset your repository to match the upstream:

```
git reset --hard @{upstream}
```

Then you can re-apply your patches using `git am` -- either one at a time or all at once.

```
git am 0001-blah-blah.patch
git am 0002-blah-blah.patch
...
```

A second option would be to create a spare branch with your work on it:

```
git branch scrap
```

Then reset your branch to the upstream:

```
git reset --hard @{upstream}
```

Then cherry-pick the commits over:

```
git cherry-pick scrap~6
git cherry-pick scrap~5
git cherry-pick scrap~4
...
```

Then trash the scrap branch:

```
git branch -D scrap
```

Comment: In place of "@{upstream}" you can even use "@{u}".

Comment: This is amazingly efficient and clean - you end up with a linear history.

Comment: I haven't tried this. Can someone explain more why it would work?

Comment: Beware: `git reset --hard` will delete unstaged modifications. Maybe it is prefearable to `stash` rather than `branch` the current workspace.

Answer (score 26):

Have you tried `git merge origin/master` ?

Your remote changes are stored in the branch `origin/master`. (Or it will, if you do `git fetch`.) Just merge the two branches - `master` and `origin/master` - like any two branches and resolve the conflicts (if any).

This may help you if you need to know how to resolve git conflicts.

[How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: Upvoted. I had the exact same issue and this fixed it. Personally I don't like vi or vim so I changed my default editor to nano. Google for instructions.

Answer (score 6):

Git says it tried to do exactly what you want (re-apply your patches on top of the newest changes from origin/master) but failed with a conflict. Right after `git pull --rebase` conflicts open an editor with the conflicted files (`git status` will list these under "both changed") and resolve the conflicts, marked in standard diff lingua. When you're done resolving the conflict throw in a `git rebase --continue` (or `git rebase --skip` if your resolution introduces no changes).

Read about his at [Stackexchange  documentation for 'Resolving merge conflicts after a Git rebase'](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-merge-conflicts-after-a-git-rebase/).

Comment: Git is pretty good at merging (or, automatically resolving "conflicts") and re-applying patches, but alas, sometimes it needs your help. In these cases, in my experience, I know of no other tool who'd do any better. You really need to manually resolve these conflicts.

Comment: Good point -- be sure to check out [git rerere](http://progit.org/2010/03/08/rerere.html).

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @sds I think it does. After you merged the branches, solved the merge conflicts, and replayed your changes on top of the master, you are back to normal. This is what wilhelmtell described.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some good answers to the same problem (only without conflict resolving):

[master branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, how to 'undiverge' branches'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452226/master-branch-and-origin-master-have-diverged-how-to-undiverge-branches)

First, you may want to review what has been changed on the remote master in comparison to your local version:

```
git log HEAD..origin/master
```

To fix your actually problem, it boils down to the same line that wilhelmtell proposed:

```
git pull --rebase
```

As you said, you will get conflicts.

Conflicts resolving is a recurring problem. If you haven't done it yet, you may take a look at `git mergetool` (see `git help mergetool` for details). To get graphical support, I would recommend to overwrite the `merge.tool` configuration. For example, if you want to use [`meld`](http://meldmerge.org/) for 3-way merges, you can use:

```
git config --global merge.tool meld
```

So after you resolved the conflict, what has `git pull --rebase` done? It merged all changes from the origin/master into your local master, and replayed your changes on top of it. Congratulations, you are back to normal.

Comment: when "git pull --rebase", it says "error: feeding unmodified ... to diffcore
Cannot pull with rebase: Your index contains uncommitted changes.
Please commit or stash them", but when "git commit", it says "Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours) nothing to commit, working directory clean"