# See exact divergence/commits between local and remote Git repo

Tags: git, diff, compare, conflict, status

**Setup:** 3 git repos - on github, local and on staging server.

I develop locally, push it to github and staging server pulls.

I don't work nor commit changes on staging server, but I must have done so long time ago. Because now I get the following message when I do `git status` (on staging server):

```
On branch SOME_BRANCH
Your branch and 'origin/SOME_BRANCH' have diverged,
and have 4 and 32 different commit(s) each, respectively.
```

**My question is:** *how do I see those exact **4** commits that are not at `origin`?*

Comment: NOTE: I tried `git log --graph --pretty --abbrev-commit --oneline`, but the history is too long. So I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [master branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, how to 'undiverge' branches'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452226/master-branch-and-origin-master-have-diverged-how-to-undiverge-branches)

Comment: Your answer as well as `git log origin..HEAD` worked great.
Re:duplicate question, the other question wants to undiverge, whereas I want to know how is it diverged.

Comment: Sure, I should have said "related"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
git rev-list origin..HEAD
```

This lists the commits in your branch (HEAD) that are not in origin.

Comment: It's helpful to add `format=%B' to get the commit messages too

Comment: Hmmm, I get: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin..HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Comment: @crmpicco try `git log origin..HEAD`. If you get an error, than probably your remote is not called `origin`. Try `git remote -v`. Does the output contain `origin`?

Comment: My remote is called `upstream` however `git rev-list upstream..HEAD` gives me the same error as @crmpico

Comment: You're probably on a different branch. In such case use `git rev-list origin/<branch name>..HEAD`, so e.g. `git rev-list origin/my-feature-branch..HEAD`, that should do the trick.

Comment: `format` doesn't seem to be a valid option for `rev-list` but `--pretty` got me log style view.

Comment: I think this applies to the main/master branch. On other branches, it returns a list of commits, even if there is no difference with the remote.

Answer (score 9):

Generically, if your remote is called *foo* and your branch is *bar*:

```
git rev-list foo/bar..HEAD
```

@charlesb is the answer for being in the master branch with remote called origin.

Answer (score 1):

show the commits exist in origin but not local:

```
git rev-list HEAD..origin --pretty
```

show the commits exist in local but not origin:

```
git rev-list origin..HEAD --pretty
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the diffs (which I think is what OP ultimately wanted), here's the full command

```
git rev-list origin..HEAD | xargs git show
```