# git merge and got this error "does not point to a commit"

Tags: git, merge, fork, fetch

I forked a repo from github.com, and also had set the upstream remote.
Below is my repo

```
[ Leezhm LIZHM ~/Developments/OF_GIT ] git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:leezhm/openFrameworks.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:leezhm/openFrameworks.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks.git (push)
```

when I used this command

```
git fetch upstream develop
git merge upstream/mac8
```

It always got the following error

```
fatal: 'upstream/mac8' does not point to a commit
```

Comment: what does 'git branch -ar' tell you?

Comment: I see [no branch of that name on github](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/branches).

Comment: '[ Leezhm LIZHM ~/Developments/OF_GIT ] git branch -ar
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/develop
  origin/mac8
  origin/master
  origin/win7
  upstream/develop
  upstream/master'

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem directly, but it helped me solve a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452226/master-branch-and-origin-master-have-diverged-how-to-undiverge-branches

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are just fetching [`upstream/develop`](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/tree/develop), while you want to fetch [`origin`](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/branches) to have [`origin/mac8`](https://github.com/leezhm/openFrameworks/tree/mac8) available.

Answer (score 2):

git fetch
git checkout "new brach" 
git pull "new branch" 
git merge "new branch"

This is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no corresponding branch in `origin/xxx`.