# How to reconcile diverged branches master and origin/master?

Tags: git

I keep getting the following when running `git status`

```
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 10 and 8 different commits each, respectively.
```

What I would like to do is pull the master branch from the remote.  I want ignore all changes on my local and get back to the current master branch.

How is this done? I have tried pulling and merging but it feels like I am doing something wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [master branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, how to 'undiverge' branches'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452226/master-branch-and-origin-master-have-diverged-how-to-undiverge-branches)

Comment: Is it really that hard to search for "origin/master diverged" using the "git" tag before asking a question?

Answer (score 3):

The way to ignore all changes and to get back to the state at origin master is with:

```
git reset --keep origin/master
```

(`--keep` is safer than `--hard` as it won't blat over any staged and unstaged changes that you might have forgotten about.)

Answer (score 2):

You can reset your local `master` branch to the `origin/master` state with :

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```