# Diverged branches, merge does not resolve the issue

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

I got this message when I run `git status`:

```
Your branch and 'origin/develop' have diverged,
and have 1 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
```

I followed the [usual steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452226/master-branch-and-origin-master-have-diverged-how-to-undiverge-branches) to resolve the issue:

- git pull
- resolve conflicts
- git commit
- git push

But I got the push rejected. Running `git status` again:

```
Your branch and 'origin/develop' have diverged,
and have 2 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
```

If I try to pull, the conflict is the same as before! I can commit again, and the story repeats over and over. It seems that Git is not able to determine that I have already done the merge. How is this possible?

**Please note:**

- I already tried `git remote update` followed by `git merge`
- I don't know how this situation was created, and I'm not able to reproduce it
- I'm not interested in trivial solutions, I already solved in practice by saving my files and re-cloning the repository. I'm looking for an analysis of the problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the resolutions provided in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452226/master-branch-and-origin-master-have-diverged-how-to-undiverge-branches)?

Comment: What is the output of 'git status'

Comment: @Zeeker, if you look at the link at the 4th line of my post, you'll see that yes, I have already looked.

Comment: @jessh: the relevant output of `git status` is in the question. I cannot recover the rest now, but it only said to solve by using `git pull`.

Comment: sorry i want to know what branch you're currently on

Comment: the first line should be "On branch..."

Comment: The branch is _develop_, pointing to _origin/develop_.