# git fetch - reviewing and modifying incoming changes

Tags: git, git-merge, git-fetch

I have read that `git pull` = `git fetch` + `git merge`, and that the latter is usually preferred because it allows one to review changes before merging them.

Our small development team is sharing a git repo on a server. My colleague just pushed and I fetched, so that his commits are now in my local repository. I can see them with:

```
git log ..origin/mybranch
```

and inspect them with:

```
git diff <hash>
```

Now let's imagine that I want to merge the changes into my working copy, but I don't like some commits or parts of one commit.
My question is:

- how do I go about "modifying" a commit before merging it into my working copy?
- in case I can do the above, will that affect the remote repository? (I have read that one should not rebase after a push, for example)
- in case I cannot do the above, how do I fix the changes after merging them? (eg. manually, ...)

In short: can someone give an overview of actions that are typically performed between a "fetch" and a "merge" to review and edit changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a merge without committing the result:

```
git merge --no-ff --no-commit <hash>
```

Then you reset the index (but not the working tree which reflects the merge)

```
git reset
```

Finally you can `git add` any file or even `git add --patch` *part* of files you want to keep in the result of that merge.
Or you can reject a merged file entirely: `git checkout HEAD -- aFile`.

You have other options in "[How do you merge selective files with `git merge`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/449541/6309)"

Comment: That is just perfect. The `git merge  --no-ff --no-commit && git reset` combo has the effect of importing the changes into my working copy, ready to be edited.

Comment: However, this approach will make the local and remote repos diverge. I solved with `git pull --rebase`, more infos [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452226/master-branch-and-origin-master-have-diverged-how-to-undiverge-branches).

Comment: @matpen True. I had forgotten about my old answer.