# Git Merging and Reparenting between 2 develop branches

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I just finished working on 2 separate develop branches that were originally branched off of the main Master branch.  Here is the flow I used in branching off of the Master Branch to create these 2 develop branches:

```
Master
  |--> DevelopBranch1
           |
            -->DevelopBranch2
```

So originally I created `DevelopBranch1` by branching from `Master`.  Then I created `DevelopBranch2` by branching off of `DevelopBranch1`.  My reasoning behind this decision was because `DevelopBranch2` depended on new changes I made within `DevelopBranch1`.

I finished making changes to `DevelopBranch1`.  Since `DevelopBranch2` did not originally branch off of `Master`, I now want to do a few things:

1) Merge `DevelopBranch1` into `Master`

2) Reparent `DevelopBranch2` into `Master`

3) Merge `DevelopBranch2` into `Master`

4) Archive `DevelopBranch1`

I was successful in Merging `DevelopBranch1` into `Master` ok by using **SourceTree** by checking out `Master` and Merging it with the latest commit from `DevelopBranch1`.

When I got to step 2, this is where I ran into issues.  I used the following git command to Reparent:

```
git checkout master
git rebase --onto DevelopBranch2
```

After the rebase command, I noticed within **SourceTree** that the latest commit from `Master` got moved to the latest commit within `DevelopBranch2`.

At this point, I tried Merging `Master` into `DevelopBranch2`.  After using this Merge and running `git status`, I got the following message

```
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 5 and 7 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

I then ran `git pull` and got this message:

```
git pull
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

This is where I'm currently stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unless you have a pretty ancient Git (e.g., 1.7.x), the `git status` output and the subsequent complaint about unmerged files don't seem to mix properly. If you *do* have such an ancient Git, this all makes sense.

Comment: @torek I was able to revert this change by using `git reset --hard master`, credit to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452226/master-branch-and-origin-master-have-diverged-how-to-undiverge-branches I think the issue I'm having is using `git rebase` correctly to reparent.

Comment: In general you want to be very careful with `git reset --hard`. What I should have just asked is: *what version of Git are you running?*

Comment: @torek git --version
git version 2.14.3.windows.1

Comment: OK, then I'm puzzled, as `git status` should have shown the merge-in-progress that was blocking the `git pull`. This may be some Windows-specific thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by the wrongly used command `git rebase --onto DevelopBranch2`. Let's illustrate by below graphs:

After step1 (merge `DevelopBranch1` into `Master`), the command history is:

```
...---A---B---C-------J       Master
           \         /
            D---F---G    DevelopBranch1
                 \
                  H--I   DevelopBranch2
```

If you use the command `git rebase --onto DevelopBranch2`, it will reset the current branch `Master` to `DevelopBranch2` as below:

```
...---A---B---C-------J      
           \         /
            D---F---G    DevelopBranch1
                 \
                  H--I   DevelopBranch2, Master
```

For you situation, you should use **`git rebase --onto Master DevelopBranch1 DevelopBranch2`** instead. Then it will reparent the `DevelopBranch2` to `Master` branch as what you expected.

First, you should reset your `Master` branch to the merge commit (the commit merged `DevelopBranch1` into `Master`), Then execute the command for step2 again. The commands used as below:

```
git checkout Master
git reset --hard <merged commit id>
git rebase --onto Master DevelopBranch1 DevelopBranch2
git push origin DevelopBranch2 -f
```

Then the step2 will be execute correctly (as below graph). And you can continue to execute step3 and step4.

```
                        H'---I'  DevelopBranch2
                       /
...---A---B---C-------J   Master
           \         /
            D---F---G    DevelopBranch1
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed!  This is an excellent explanation and I do appreciate you taking the time in giving the details.  I hope this helps others who run into this issue as well!