# On local GIT, how to merge master with origin/master when local master is ahead or on separate branch compared to origin/master?

Tags: git

When we do a fetch or pull and the local master branch is behind the origin/master branch or if the local master is on separate branch compared to origin/master, then how to bring local master in sync with origin/master?

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/images/remote-branches-3.png

Comment: did you had a look to `git pull` ?

Comment: That's what `git pull` does. It is a fetch + a merge (or rebase). Are you finding something different? Pulling is covered just a bit further in [that document](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [master branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, how to 'undiverge' branches'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452226/master-branch-and-origin-master-have-diverged-how-to-undiverge-branches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform the merge (or rebase) manually just like any other branch.

```
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git merge origin/master

0b743 < a6b4c < f4265 < 31b8e < 190a3 [origin/master]
                     \               \   
                      < a38de < 893cf < abc123 [master]
```

Or you can use `git pull origin master` which will `git fetch origin` and `git merge origin/master` for you same as above.

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

Or you can avoid an unnecessary bookkeeping merge and replay your local changes on top of the remote ones with `git pull --rebase`. This is a `git fetch origin` plus a `git rebase origin/master`.

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase origin master

0b743 < a6b4c < f4265 < 31b8e < 190a3 [origin/master]
                                     \   
                                      < a38de1 < 893cf1 [master]
```

Comment: While this answer presents rebasing as though it were a no-brainer, there actually are pros and cons to rebasnig on pull.  Understand that immediately after a rebase, *all* of the rewritten commits that replace your local commits are untested - not just the final result, as with a merge