# How to forward new changes to 1 month older feature branch

Tags: git

We have 2 master branch test/live.I created a feature branch from our live branch and developed. When I tried to merge commits to test branch I conflicted and created another copy of test branch as a feature/test branch and I merged my feature/live branch to it and resolved conflict so I could merged my changes to master/test. But I forgot to change to live/feature branch and started to develop on copy of test branch for a month almost. Now I need to forward my changes to master/live branch but I cant merge my test/feautre branch to live because of the other ones changes. So I need to forward my commits to feature/live branch. Whats is the best to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, your copy of "test" branch and the original "test" branch have diverged.

You need to perform either a git merge or git rebase, as is described excellently in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452226/master-branch-and-origin-master-have-diverged-how-to-undiverge-branches/2452610).