# Git Merge - Question related to local vs remote repository and how it could affect the master branch?

Tags: git, github, merge, git-branch, remote-access

I'm pretty new with using Git and I am trying to understand the git merge function a bit better. Hope someone can explain this to me, I would appreciate it!

So, I'm working on a local testing branch and I'm seeing the following errors:

```
On branch Agata
Your branch and 'origin/Agata' have diverged,
and have 1 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)
```

My questions are

1. How to resolve this issue
2. Will this merge affect the master branch at all?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This looks like `git status` output. As such, it is not "errors", but "status".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [master branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, how to 'undiverge' branches'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452226/master-branch-and-origin-master-have-diverged-how-to-undiverge-branches)

Comment: You have already started merging. You must either finish the current merge, or end it, before you can start another. (As @j6t said this is not an *error*, it's just information telling you what's going on.)